Bad roll down position with TinyMCE
I have a TinyMCE editor included in a form, and when I want to roll down a menu, like text size (h1n h2, h3...), the position of it is bugged, it is positioned at the bottom, like this:
roll down position in editor
I have no idea of what I can do, I found nothing in the Tiny docs...
I know that the menu is 1300px top, but why ? =>
<div role="menu" 
    class="tox-menu tox-collection tox-collection--list tox-selected-menu" 
    style="position: absolute; left: 474.406px; top: 1333.44px; max-height: 350px; overflow: hidden auto; min-width: 130px;" data-alloy-placement="southeast">
</div>

